# Как с помощью rsync (или другой утилиты) синхронизировать только файлы, измененные за неделю?

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование, rsync

Синхронизировать нужно файл из каталога сайта, рекурсивно, но синхронизировать только то, что изменено или появилось нового в течении этой недели. То есть, считаем, что все файлы старше недели в бэкапе уже есть.

В качестве хранилища использую webdav yandex disk, а он очень тормозной и не поддерживает ни сравнение по дате модификации, ни контрольные суммы. Есть только сравнение по размеру. Пока выполняет проверку по всем папкам, можно уже выспаться))). Хочу ускорить процесс.

Comment: утилиту `find` с параметром `-ctime -7` (*время последнего изменения владельца или прав доступа к файлу (в днях)*) пробовали? Сначала находите изменившиеся файлы, затем копируете их.

Answer (score 4):

1. найти файлы (в текущем каталоге и глубже), дата модификации которых меньше семи дней:

   ```
   $ find -type f -mtime -7
   ```

   список будет содержать и относительный путь к файлам.
2. сформировать из этого списка ряд команд вида `rsync опции-rsync путь/к/файлу место-назначения` можно с помощью программы *xargs*:

   ```
   $ find ... | xargs -I'{}' rsync опции-rsync '{}' место-назначения
   ```
3. для того, чтобы правильно обрабатывались пробелы и прочие спец-символы в именах файлов/каталогов, имеет смысл добавить программе *find* опцию `-print0`, а программе *xargs*, соответственно, `-0`:

   ```
   $ find ... -print0 | xargs -0 -I'{}' rsync ...
   ```